# Morphia - CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class - But class is registered

Tags: java, mongodb, codec, bson, morphia

i've got a problem i have not been facing yet.
I want to store a Object with an embedded Object in MongoDB using Morphia.

It seems like it perfectly understand how to de-/serialize the top-level-class but not the embedded one. Here are the two classes:

```
@Entity(value = "cb-homes", noClassnameStored = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class DatastoreHome extends DatastoreEntity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Indexed(options = @IndexOptions(unique = true, sparse = true, background = true))
    private UUID uniqueId;
    @Property("homes")
    @Embedded
    private Map<String, List<HomeLocation>> homeLocations;

    public List<String> getHomeNameList() {
        List<HomeLocation> locations = homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName());
        if(locations == null) {
            locations = new ArrayList<>();
            homeLocations.put(Bukkit.getServerName(), locations);
        }
        return locations.stream().map(HomeLocation::getHomeName).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Location> getHomeLocationList() {
        List<HomeLocation> locations = homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName());
        if(locations == null) {
            locations = new ArrayList<>();
            homeLocations.put(Bukkit.getServerName(), locations);
        }
        return locations.stream().map(HomeLocation::getLocation).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean hasSetBaseHome() {
        return getHomeLocation("home") != null;
    }

    public Location getBaseHomeLocation() {
        return getHomeLocation("home");
    }

    public Location getHomeLocation(String homeName) {
        List<HomeLocation> locations = homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName());
        if(locations == null) {
            locations = new ArrayList<>();
            homeLocations.put(Bukkit.getServerName(), locations);
        }
        return locations.stream()
                .filter(location -> location.getHomeName().equals(homeName.toLowerCase()))
                .findAny()
                .map(HomeLocation::getLocation)
                .filter(location -> location.getWorld().getName() != "world")
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public boolean isHomeAlreadySet(String name) {
        return getHomeNameList().contains(name.toLowerCase());
    }

    public HomeLocation addHomeLocation(String homeName, Location location) {
        List<HomeLocation> locations = homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName());
        if(locations == null) {
            locations = new ArrayList<>();
            homeLocations.put(Bukkit.getServerName(), locations);
        }
        if(isHomeAlreadySet(homeName)) {
            locations.remove(getHomeLocation(homeName));
        }
        HomeLocation homeLocation = new HomeLocation();
        homeLocation.setHomeName(homeName.toLowerCase());
        homeLocation.setLocation(location);
        homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName()).add(homeLocation);
        return homeLocation;
    }

    public void removeBaseHomeLocation() {
        removeHomeLocation("home");
        addHomeLocation("home", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    public boolean removeHomeLocation(String homeName) {
        if(homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName()) == null) {
            homeLocations.put(Bukkit.getServerName(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        return homeLocations.get(Bukkit.getServerName()).removeIf(location -> location.getHomeName().equals(homeName));
    }

    static {
        datastore.ensureIndexes(DatastoreHome.class);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Embedded
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class HomeLocation extends DatastoreEntity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String homeName;
    @Property("location")
    private Document document;

    public Location getLocation() {
        return deserialize(document);
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        document = serialize(location);
    }

    private Document serialize(Location location) {
        return new Document("world", location.getWorld())
                .append("x", location.getX())
                .append("y", location.getY())
                .append("z", location.getZ())
                .append("yaw", location.getYaw())
                .append("pitch", location.getPitch());
    }

    private Location deserialize(Document document) {
        return new Location(Bukkit.getWorld((String) get("world")), (double) get("x"), (double) get("y"), (double) get("z"), (float) get("yaw"), (float) get("pitch"));
    }

    private Object get(String key) {
        return document.get(key);
    }

    static {
        datastore.ensureIndexes(HomeLocation.class);
    }

}
```

As you can see both classes are added to the Morphia index via static class initialization. This works for all other classes just for the HomeLocation.class it does not work.

Have you guys any ideas how to fix this?
I also tried adding the classes manually to the Morphia index when initializing Morphia but that also does not work.

I hope you can help me.

Kind Regards,

Fabian Schmidt

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Also, you don't need an @Id in the embedded object since it will just be represented inside a field in the collection DatastoreHome objects.

Comment: Are you using Lombok annotations on your class? Not sure if that's tested with Morphia.

Comment: Lombok works perfectly fine with Morphia we use it in every other class too. The problem was that Morphia does not use the en/decoders from MongoDB, it comes with its own. Because of that Morphia did not know how to map the Document class and failed. I got a workaround for it by hooking manually into the BSON.class and adding en/decoders. Unluckily this problem is nowhere mentioned so it took like three days to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post, but sharing my solution I hope to help someone else.

In your case, you should change this:

```
@Property("homes")
@Embedded
private Map<String, List<HomeLocation>> homeLocations;
```

into this:

```
@Embedded("homes")
private Map<String, List<HomeLocation>> homeLocations;
```

And no need to add the @Embedded annotation on top of HomeLocation class.